# If I have mono and .NET Core installed on linux which one will run my code?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core, mono

I'd installed monodevelop on my linux and build an application with it. It run, but is very slow compared to a windows run, both in release mode. If I install .NET Core and run this app, will it be runing with mono or .Net Core?

**EDIT:**

Sorry I didn't told you details but now I understand why it run very slow. The library was created with .Net Standard so it can be used by .NET Framework and .NET Core applications, but the application I made and use the library is a .NET Framework Windows Forms. So basically it run as any .NET Famework code and doesn't benefit from .NET Core optimizations.

But the question remains. If I got two of them instaled (.NET Core and Mono) and I ran a .NET Core application, which one will run the application .NET Core or Mono.

Comment: Hi can run .Follow the url https://audministrator.wordpress.com/2018/08/05/windows-10-running-asp-net-core-2-0-on-mono/

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/running-asp-net-core-2-0-via-mono/

Comment: MonoDevelop 7.x does support .NET Core development, but you probably created a legacy .NET Framework compatible project and ran it on Mono. That must have significant performance differences. No, traditional projects won't run on .NET Core without proper migration, so even if you install .NET Core runtime, your project won't run on it automatically.

Comment: Thank you and sorry, I forgot to write details before. I edited the question, and now I understand it better.